# Sharing Live photo on WhatsApp in Swift 3 using UIActivityViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, uiactivityviewcontroller, apple-live-photos

I am sharing Image,video and LivePhoto using `UIActivityViewController` on Different social media.

But when i am sharing **LivePhoto** on **WhatsApp** ,something like below is happening :

1. when ActivityViewController present -> click on WhatsApp -> it present contact list for second and quickly dismiss and when i try to print error using `ActivityViewController` Completion handler it print something like this :

> [core] SLComposeViewController remoteViewController:
>    didTerminateWithError:
>   Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}  [core]
>   SLComposeViewController completeWithResult: 0  [core]
>   SLComposeViewController skipping explicit dismiss because
>   isBeingDismissed is already 1  SLComposeViewController dealloc

```
I have tried with this code : 

PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: selectedAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (imgData, str, image, info) in

                activityItems.append(imgData!)

                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
                activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
                activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
                    //Do whatever you want
                    print("activityType ----- \(activityType) || error ----- \(error)")
                }
                // present the view controller
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.navigationController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            })
```

can anyone help me with please.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like WhatsApp doesn't support live photos. Can you share it somewhere else, like iMessage? If it works everywhere else, it's probably WhatsApp that doesn't support it.

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, If Whatsapp doesn't support live photo then, when I share still image from live photo it shows random errors sometimes like above and sometimes like "This item cannot be shared, Please select different item"

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : i have added code above

Comment: image data is nsdata or else

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : yes NSData

Comment: see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165222/sending-custom-data-via-uiactivityviewcontroller or append the image see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417047/whatsapp-image-sharing-ios?rq=1,

Comment: but your data is high , so connection Interrupted

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : refered your given link but this for specific whatsApp but i need to share my photos and Live photos on each social media which are given in UIActivityViewController so this is not useful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I got the solution

I have removed `UIActivityController` and Used `UIDocumentInteractionController` like below :

```
let imageLocalPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("public.jpeg")
                
                if let imageData = imgData {
                    do {
                        try imageData.write(to: imageLocalPath, options: .atomic)
                        self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: imageLocalPath)
//                        self.documentInteractionController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                        self.documentInteractionController.uti = "public.image"
                        self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self
                        self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
```

Then In delegate method of it :

**For WhatsApp** :

```
func documentInteractionController(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController, willBeginSendingToApplication application: String?) {
        print("Application ----- \(String(describing: application))")
        
    if(check for whatsApp condition){
        let imageLocalPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("whatsAppTmp.wai")
        if let imageData = selectedImageData {
            do {
                try imageData.write(to: imageLocalPath, options: .atomic)
                controller.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                controller.url = imageLocalPath
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```