# Passing data between an iOS app on different devices

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, airdrop

I’m looking for the best and efficient way to pass a Nested Array [[String]], from my app to the same app on another iPhone.

If let say for example, I have this Array saved on my app:

```
let array = [[“John”, “27”, “First”, “Castle”],[“Tom”, “25”, “Second”, “Boat”]]
```

I want to add a Share Button on my App that will allow this array to be shared via Bluetooth/Airdrop/Any Convenient Way between 2 iPhones.

Ideally click share, via airdrop, other user click accepts and clicks open with the app. And data is loaded. What is the best approach In order to achieve this. I looked at Share Extension and UIActivityViewController but can’t see what are the differences about them and what is best for my case to simply send data and receive data from and to my app.

Comment: would the sharing is required to be YourApp <-> YourApp. 
or YourApp -> AirDrop -> File App

Comment: My app doesn’t have to communicate together with the other one. It can be a simple text string airdropped and then the other user would click accept and import that string to his app. I looked at UTI using custom format and .txt file but can’t get it to open the data in my app. I found a lot of information about sharing the data out but not much about actually importing it to my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have said,

You could just use the UIActivityViewController to export your data to AirDrop (or etc)
and using the exported UTI, your app could open it once it detected.

for Sharing, you will have to use a custom data format (or file) and you can refer to this post, [Sending custom data via UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165222/sending-custom-data-via-uiactivityviewcontroller)

and for reading your custom file, here is a good tutorial of how to implement the Exported UTI https://www.raywenderlich.com/8413525-universal-type-identifiers-tutorial-for-ios-importing-and-exporting-app-data

Cheers,
Kel

Answer (score 1):

One option (and probably the easiest) is to use iCloud, specifically the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.

More information here :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Comment: I had a look at Share Extension and UTI can’t see what the difference between them is. A simple AirDrop share, open with click on my app would do it but not sure what to use.

Comment: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is for sharing between devices signed into the same Apple ID. It seems OP wants to share between multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

use UIActivityViewController to export your data using AirDrop. You can read the same in your app on other phone when it detects the exported UTI.